# Container height based on every 2 images row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I´m working on this [website](http://testweb.ivanhugo.com/portraitlist)

I´m doing the resize of vertical images using this script:

```
function Gallery(selector) {
  this.add_module = function (type, image) {

    var portrait_text = image.next('.portrait_text');

    var container = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'gallery_container'
    }).append(image).append(portrait_text);

    if (type == 'horizontal') {
      var h_ar = image.attr('height') / image.attr('width');
      var c_width = selector.width();
      var c_height = selector.width() * h_ar
      container.css({
        'width': c_width,
        'height': c_height
      })
    }
    if (type == 'vertical') {
      var c_width = v_width;
      var c_height = v_height
      container.css({
        'width': Math.floor(v_width),
        'height': v_height
      })
    }
    container.css({
      'float': 'left',
    })
    container.find('img').attr({
      'width': '100%',
      'height': '100%'
    })
    container.attr('ar', c_height / c_width)
    container.appendTo(selector);

    //container.children('img').fitToBox();
  }

  this.resized = function () {
    //console.log(sel)
    $('.gallery_container').each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr('ar') >= 1) { // vertical
        $(this).css({
          'width': sel.width() / 2,
          'height': sel.width() / 2 * $(this).attr('ar')
        })
      } else { // horizontal
        $(this).css({
          'width': sel.width(),
          'height': sel.width() * $(this).attr('ar')
        })
      }
    })
  }
  var _this = this;
  var gutter = 0;
  // start vars for counting on vertical images
  var v_counter = 0;
  var w_pxls = 0;
  var h_pxls = 0;
  var v_ar;
  // iterates through images looking for verticals
  selector.children('img').each(function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).attr('width')) < parseInt($(this).attr('height'))) {
      v_counter++;
      h_pxls += $(this).attr('height');
      w_pxls += $(this).attr('width');
      v_ar = $(this).attr('height') / $(this).attr('width')
    }
  })
  // calculates average ar for vertical images (anything outside from aspect ratio will be croped)
  var h_avrg = Math.floor(h_pxls / v_counter);
  var w_avrg = Math.floor(w_pxls / v_counter);
  var v_width = Math.floor((selector.width()) / 2);
  var v_height = v_width * v_ar;
  var sel = selector;
  selector.children('img').each(function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).attr('width')) > parseInt($(this).attr('height'))) {
      _this.add_module('horizontal', $(this));
    } else {
      _this.add_module('vertical', $(this));
    }
  })
  $(window).bind('resize', _this.resized);
}

var gallery = new Gallery($('#gallery_images_inner'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mZ2Ks/

The problem I have is that the script makes all the container the same of height (depending on the last image on the page I think), so for example first images resizes in a bad way. If you look at the example, **all 2 image rows have a height of 613px.**

Is there any way how can I control **each two images container** to calculate it´s own height based on its images, it looks like right now it **calculates the last image resize height and apply it to all other containers**

**Applying height: auto instead of 100% won´t work cause it will not make the images fit the height of the vertical container.**

How can I fix the script?

Comment: It looks like you'll need to move $('.gallery_container').each outside the calculations so that sel is updated for each image. I've added a fiddle to your question for anyone who feels like tackling it.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle isherwood, let's see if someone can help me out :)

Comment: @grafiker can you perhaps add a picture of what you want to achieve. i am not really following

Comment: and i dont think you should resize them like this because it makes the page load kind of slow. instead resize them in an image editor and add to portfolio and than link it to the actual picture.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a easy way. but frist: your gallery-script calculates a average aspect ratio for all images inside. there is no simple way to change this behavior.

But you can do this simple workaround: put echt two images in their own gallery!

```
var gallery1 = new Gallery($('#gallery_images_inner1'));
var gallery2 = new Gallery($('#gallery_images_inner2'));
var gallery3 = new Gallery($('#gallery_images_inner3'));
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mZ2Ks/2/ - i had to clean up your html code a little bit - you copied the "javascript affected" html code from (i assume) firebug, but you should have copied the plain html from source code direct (CTRL + U in firefox).

Comment: Thanks Stephan, you are right, the problem is that the aspect ratio calculates an average for all images. I don't think the workaround you put will work, as the client will upload new images, so I can't just control their own gallery with this approach... Thanks anyway!